# How do I use a setTimeout function on some images?

Tags: javascript, image, settimeout

I am creating a game using javascript, it starts off with six blurred images, once the image is selected it shows the unblurred image. I am wanting the unblurred images to be shown for 2 seconds, it then needs to go back to the blurred image.

The code I have works fine, however when I have tried to create a setTimeout function the images dont change anymore. I have tried to create it as an array and have the time at the end but it didnt work. I have also tried putting a time at the end of the showpicture function but again it didnt work. Can someone please help me create the setTimeout function.

My working code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Who Am I? </title>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var imageone = document.getElementById("Zero");
        var imagetwo = document.getElementById("One");
        var imagethree = document.getElementById("Two");
        var imagefour = document.getElementById("Three");
        var imagefive = document.getElementById("Four");
        var imagesix = document.getElementById("Five");

        function init() {
        init1();
        init2();
        init3();
        init4();
        init5();
        init6();
        };

        function init1 () {
        var imageone = document.getElementById("Zero");
        imageone.onclick = showAnswerone;
        }

        function init2 () {
        var imagetwo = document.getElementById("One");
        imagetwo.onclick = showAnswertwo;
        }

        function init3 () {
        var imagethree = document.getElementById("Two");
        imagethree.onclick = showAnswerthree;
        }

        function init4 () {
        var imagefour = document.getElementById("Three");
        imagefour.onclick = showAnswerfour;
        }

        function init5 () {
        var imagefive = document.getElementById("Four");
        imagefive.onclick = showAnswerfive;
        }

        function init6 () {
        var imagesix = document.getElementById("Five");
        imagesix.onclick = showAnswersix;
        }


        window.onload = init;

        function showAnswerone () {
        var imageone = document.getElementById("Zero");
        init1();
        imageone.src="Zero.jpg";
        }

        function showAnswertwo () {
        var imagetwo = document.getElementById("One");
        init2();
        imagetwo.src="One.jpg";
        }


        function showAnswerthree () {
        var imagethree = document.getElementById("Two");
        init3();
        imagethree.src="Two.jpg";
        }


        function showAnswerfour () {
        var imagefour = document.getElementById("Three");
        init4();
        imagefour.src="Three.jpg";
        }

        function showAnswerfive () {
        var imagefive = document.getElementById("Four");
        imagefive.src="Four.jpg";
        }

        function showAnswersix () {
        var imagesix = document.getElementById("Five");
        init5();
        imagesix.src="Five.jpg";
        }

        function submitForm()
        {
        var var_one = 0, var_two = 0, var_three = 0;
        var var_four = 0, var_five = 0, var_six = 0;
        }

        function var_oneb(){
            var_one=5;
            return true;
        }

        function var_onea(){
            var_one=0;
            return true;
        }

        function var_twob(){
            var_two=5;
            return true;
        }
        function var_twoa(){
            var_two=0;
            return true;
        }

        function var_threeb(){
            var_three=5;
            return true;
        }

        function var_threea(){
            var_three=0;
            return true;
        }


        function var_fourb(){
            var_four=5;
            return true;
        }

        function var_foura(){
        var_four=0;
        return true;
        }


        function var_fiveb(){
            var_five=5;
            return true;
        }

        function var_fivea(){
            var_five=0;
            return true;
        }

        function var_sixb(){
            var_six=5;
            return true;
        }

        function var_sixa(){
            var_six=0;
            return true;
        }


        function results_addition() {
        var var_results=var_one+var_two+var_three+var_four+var_five+var_six;
        if(var_results<=29){
            document.getElementById('choice1').value="Not all answers are correct";
        }
        else{
        if(var_results>=30){
        document.getElementById('choice1').value="All answers are correct";
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById('choice1').value="All answers are correct";
        }
        }
        }

</script>

<style>
    body {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    }

    div#grid {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: 50;
        margin-right: 50;
    }

    table {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 40px;
        top: 40px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 160px;
        height: 110px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        align-content: stretch;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-family: verdana, arial;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-family: verdana, arial;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="grid">
    <h2> Who Am I? </h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> <img id = "Zero" src = "Zeroblur.jpg"> </td>
    <td> <img id = "One" src = "Oneblur.jpg"> </td>
    <td> <img id = "Two" src = "Twoblur.jpg"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> <img id = "Three" src = "Threeblur.jpg"> </td>
    <td> <img id = "Four" src = "Fourblur.jpg"> </td>
    <td> <img id = "Five" src = "Fiveblur.jpg"> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h3> I am a Rugby League Player. </h3>
    <h3> Click on me to reveal my identity! </h3>
    <br>
    <h3>Which Player am I</h3>
    <hr>
    <form action="">
    <h3>Player 1 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>  
    Shaun Johnson <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra1" VALUE="0" onclick="var_onea()">   
    Sonny Bill Williams <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra1" VALUE="5" onclick="var_oneb()">
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <h3>Player 2 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>   
    Gareth Widdop <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra2" VALUE="0" onclick="var_twoa()">   
    Sam Tomkins <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra2" VALUE="5" onclick="var_twob()"> 
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <h3>Player 3 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>   
    James Graham <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra3" VALUE="5" onclick="var_threea()">   
    Sam Burgess <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra3" VALUE="10" onclick="var_threeb()">
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <h3>Player 4 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>  
    Matthew Scott <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra4" VALUE="5" onclick="var_foura()">   
    Johnathon Thurston <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra4" VALUE="10" onclick="var_fourb()">
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <h3>Player 5 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>  
    Neil Lowe <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra5" VALUE="5" onclick="var_fivea()">   
    Danny Brough <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra5" VALUE="10" onclick="var_fiveb()">
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <h3>Player 6 </h3>
<center>
    <h3>  
    Mitch Garbutt  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra6" VALUE="5" onclick="var_sixa()">   
    Ryan Hall <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Ra6" VALUE="10" onclick="var_sixb()">
    </h3>
</center>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
<center>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" onclick="results_addition()"> Your Score:
    <INPUT TYPE="text" id="choice1" NAME="choice1" VALUE="" SIZE=30> 
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better to post the code that isn't working

Comment: What exactly would you like to have threaded in `setTimeout`? Your code is a bit of a mess, can't really guess what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to have the unblurred image displayed for 2 seconds. Im new to javascript. The unblurred images are (Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six) the blurred images have blur on the end of each so Zeroblur, Oneblur and so on.

Comment: I have tried to create it by having: setTimeout (function() { The code for the blurred images was in between, } 2000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the unblurred images and then switch back to the blurred ones use this (four in this example):

```
function showAnswerfive () {
    var imagefive = document.getElementById("Four");
    imagefive.src="Four.jpg";
    setTimeout (function() {
        imagefive.src="Fourblur.jpg";
    },2000);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you can optimize those function, basically chunk down to one function, and store the pictures like so:

**JS:**

```
function showAnswerById (id) {
    var imagefive = document.getElementById(id);
    var blurredImage = imagefive.getAttribute("blurred-src");
    var unBlurredImage = imagefive.getAttribute("unblurred-src");
    imagefive.src=unBlurredImage;
    setTimeout (function() {
        imagefive.src=blurredImage ;
    },2000);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img id="Zero" blurred-src="Zeroblur.jpg" unblurred-src="Zero.jpg" src="Zeroblur.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: My pleasure, also check out my edit, I suggested a edit, your code will get a lot cleaner just by that!

Comment: Okay thanks :) Its working exactly how I had planned it.